# is checking a complex expression in a loop optimized by the compiler?

Tags: c, loops, optimization

(If this is a duplicate please point me to an answer)

I have two scenarios where a loop is checking a complex expression over and over again (a complex expression would consist of math operations and retrieving data):

```
for (int i = 0; i < expression; i++) {
    // stuff
}

for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++) {
    if (i == expression) break;
}
```

I'm wondering if it's more efficient to pre-calculate the expression and check against a known value like so

```
int known = expression;
for (int i = 0; i < known; i++) {
    // stuff
}

for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++) {
    if (i == known) break;
}
```

or if it's done by the compiler automatically.

For reference, I'm running the loop ~700 000 000 times and the expression is something like `structure->arr[j] % n` or `sqrt(a * n + b)`

Is it even worth it?

Comment: The answer is "it depends very heavily on the complexity of the expression, and the exact compiler you're using; you should benchmark to find out if the source code optimization is worth doing."

Comment: What @TavianBarnes said.  Is there any reason you can't just try it both ways, and see?

Comment: Also, note `structure->arr[i] % n` is not loop-invariant so I can't imagine that particular expression being hoisted.

Comment: In your examples, `sqrt(a * n + b)` will be invariant to the loop and could be calculated outside the loop, _if_ the variables cannot be modified by function calls in the loop (side effects). If the compiler can determine this, it may move this calculation outside the loop to be done once. If _some_ variables may be modified in the loop, the compiler may still move the invariant calculations of the expression to outside the loop

Comment: ...and if you don't trust your compiler to do this, then do it yourself (possibly at the expense of some clarity of the code).

Comment: You can visit gcc.godbolt.com and check generated assembly by yourself. You don't have to actually know what it means, since you can just write two functions and check if they're equivalent or not.

Comment: I wouild always go with explicitly removing as much from the loop expression as possible, if for no other reason than ease of debugging, (and that is a very good reason:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compiler is able to detect that calculating `expression` will give the same result every time, it will only do the calculation once.

The tricky part is: **"If the compiler is able to ...."**

Compilers are very smart and will probably be successful in most cases. But why take the chance?

**Just write that extra line to do the calculation before the loop as you did in your second example.**

By doing that you send a clear message to the compiler about `expression` being constant within the loops. Further it may also help your co-workers to easier understand the code.

That said... you yourself must be sure that `expression` is in fact the same every time. Let's look at your example:

> the expression is something like structure->arr[i] % n or sqrt(a * n + b)

Now the first one, i.e. `structure->arr[i] % n` depends on the loop variable `i` so it will be a **big mistake** to move the code outside the loop.

The second (i.e. `sqrt(a * n + b)`) looks better provided that `a n b` doesn't change inside the loop.

Comment: Decomplexing an expession is also better/easier for debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote `i` accidentally, both expressions are meant to stay constant throughout looping